# Using FaceBook API oauth, how would I get an access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have this code:

```
<?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXX',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

?>
    <body>
        <h1>SocialBlocks: Facebook Login with OAuth 2.0</h1>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div>
                Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <h3>PHP Session</h3>
        <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

        <?php if ($user): ?>
            <h3>You</h3>
            <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
            https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/feed

            <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
            <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
        <?php else: ?>
            <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
        <?php endif ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I have a problem, I wanna fetch more information like https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/feed but I heard I need an access token?

Thank you, can someone help me by showing just a little snippet of code about how to go about this? :)

Comment: thanks for the credentials :)

Comment: Friendly suggestion: Avoid sharing ANY kind of sensitive information on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a User Access Token, once you have authenticated a user using Facebook SDK. You can find the information about user authentication [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens).

Now, once the user is authenticated, you can retrieve a user's Access Token by:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```